# Site looks worse after expanding view to wide. Not sure why changing max-width fixes the issue

Tags: html, css

I was notified that my site has a small css bug in which the side bar bleeds into the right text if the view is expanded wide. 
site

Here is my css:

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1160px;
}

.masthead {
  background-color: $hot-orange;
  float:left;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 32%;

  @include mobile {
    height: 35%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.main-body {
  float: right;
  width: 68%;
  padding: 0 10% 0 8%;

  @include mobile {
    height: 65%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

my html:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="masthead clearfix">
        <div class="masthead-content">
          <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/" class="site-avatar"><img src="{{ site.avatar }}" /></a>

          <div class="site-info">
            <h1 class="site-name"><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">{{ site.name }}</a></h1>
            <p class="site-description">{{ site.description }}</p>
          </div>

          {% include nav.html %}
          <div class="wrapper-footer">
            <footer class="footer">
              {% include svg-icons.html %}
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="main-body" id="main" role="main" class="container">
        {{ content }}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Once the view goes past the 1160 in the chrome dev tools tool, the left pink nav bar starts bleeding into the right. Any idea why? The problem is fixed if I change the max-width to like 1600px, but I don't know why or what the problem is. Why are the two left and right halves bleeding into each other when I have the width adding up to 100%?

Comment: Could you provide working code? I put this into a snippet and it doesn't work for me - I cant see what you are talking about which is kind of hard to debug CSS.

Comment: visit iamthemangosteen.com or download the repo at https://github.com/Jwan622/Jwan622.github.io and run it with jekyll serve

Comment: I also fixed the problem by taking away max-width all together from the container and replacing it with width 100%

Comment: That has to do with the fact that your sidebar is `fixed`, which means its always relative to the window and not the container.

Answer (score 0):

Because your sidebar is positioned `fixed` it calculated the `32%` width from the document, so its based on full width of your window instead of your `container`. The simplest way to fix it is to give your sidebar a max-width as well, this time a calculated max-width which is the same percentage, but this time calculated of your containers max-width (so: `1260 / 100 * 32`). Try this:

```
.masthead { max-width: 403px; }
```

Comment: but then this will break responsiveness and adaptiveness of the masthead

Comment: No it won't. A `max-width` does not mess with the 'adaptiveness'. Your site was going to have white spaces on both sides nonetheless, this isn;t changing anything but keeping it in bounds.